# Why does str.encode('utf-8') produce UnicodeDecodeError in my python script?

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8

When running the following code (which just prints out file names):

```
print filename
```

It throws the following error:

```
File "myscript.py", line 78, in __listfilenames
print filename
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 13: ordinal not in range(128)
```

So to fix this, I tried changing `print filename` to `print filename.encode('utf-8')` which didn't fix the problem.

The script **only** fails when trying read a filename such as `Coé.jpg`.

Any ideas how I can modify `filename` so the script continues to work when it comes acorss a special character?

NB. I'm a python noob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`filename` is already encoded. It is already a byte string and doesn't need encoding *again*.

But since you asked it to be encoded, Python first has to **decode** it  for you, and it can only do that with the default ASCII encoding. That implicit decoding fails:

```
>>> 'Coé.jpg'
'Co\xc3\xa9.jpg'
>>> 'Coé.jpg'.decode('utf8')
u'Co\xe9.jpg'
>>> 'Coé.jpg'.decode('utf8').encode('utf8')
'Co\xc3\xa9.jpg'
>>> 'Coé.jpg'.encode('utf8')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 2: ordinal not in range(128)
```

If you wanted encoded bytestrings, you don't have to do any encoding at all. Remove the `.encode('utf8')`.

You probably need to read up on Python and Unicode. I recommend:

- [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) by Joel Spolsky
- [Pragmatic Unicode](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html) by Ned Batchelder
- The [Python Unicode HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html)

The rule of thumb is: decode as early as you can, encode as late as you can. That means when you receive data, decode to Unicode objects, when you need to pass that information to something else, encode only then. Many APIs can do the decoding and encoding as part of their job; `print` will encode to the codec used by the terminal, for example.

Comment: But if I run the same script without `.encoded().` bit, my script then gives me this error `UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 13: ordinal not in range(128)`

Comment: @Nadine: perhaps. You could well have *other* errors in your code where you are mixing unicode and byte strings.

Comment: I've updated my question to better describe the problem as works correctly and only fails on special chars. I will review your updated answer and the links now

Comment: @Nadine: are you saying that the *full traceback* for your error now points to `print filename` and gives you a `UnicodeDecodeError`? I am very skeptical that that is the case.

Comment: You're right to be sckeptical, the issue is a lot deeper than I thought. However, you're links have massively helped me understand Python unicode and as such, will mark this as accepted.